# Why does AND statement not return true when the input satisfies both conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to automate a process. I've hit a roadblock and can't understand why this code doesn't work. I would love to find what I'm missing and an explanation as to why it doesn't work. I'm trying to change the interior color of a cell if it's value is between two parameters which are filled out in a user form. For example, if there were values 1-4 in a range(including decimals) and user wants to highlight all numbers between 2-3.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim r As Range
Dim i As Range
Dim q As Range


Set r = Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlToRight))
Set i = Range(r, r.End(xlDown))



For Each q In i

    If q.Value <= txtMaxHot.Value And q.Value >= txtMinHot.Value Then

        q.Interior.Color = rgbGreen

    End If

Next q

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the values of `txtMaxHot` and `txtMinHot` and how is `And` not working?

Comment: txtMaxHot may be different type with q.value, make it same, if q.value is numeric, change the txtmaxhot and txtminhot to variabel of long

Comment: @BigBen `txtMaxHot` and `txtMinHot` are user inputs. If the range contained noninteger numbers from 1-100 but wanted to highlight all numbers between 20 and 50 `txtmaxhot` would be 50 and `txtminhot` would be 20. Sorry for not clarifying. As for the `And` statement not working, it proceeds to ending the if instead of changing the interior color.

Comment: @user11982798 suggestion is good one. You can probably compare them by using type conversion like `cDec(q.Value) <= cDec(txtMaxHot.Value)`

Comment: @user11982798 That seems to have fixed my problem. Thanks so much. Would it be possible for my range to be read as numeric but my user inputs be read as string?

Comment: Well if there text boxes, then most certainly.

Comment: @BigBen As we talk about it, it only becomes more obvious haha